# Reading ConfigurationSection value using custom configuration and represent into domain object(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have in the app.config file a section as

```
<OurType>
 <sometype typename = "type1" Iscolor="true"/>
 <sometype typename = "type2" Iscolor="false"/>
</Ourtype>
```

What I need to do is to polulate this values into my domain object which is as under

```
Class OurType
{

  public string TypeName{get;set;}
  public string IsColor{get;set;}
}
```

I want to do something like

`list<OurType> obj = ConfigurationManager.GetCollection(Something)` which will read the configuration section of that portion and then populate the List.

How to do it using custom configuration?

Thanks

I am using C#3.0 and dot net framework 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way? Check out the [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com) add-in for Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 up on Codeplex. It gives you a nice UI to work with, and generates all those thorny configuration classes and a XML schema to enable Visual Studio intellisense in your config sections for you - all very neatly and easily.

Check it out!

If you want to do it "by hand", make sure to check out Jon Rista's three-part series on .NET 2.0 configuration up on CodeProject.

- [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful!

Marc