# What is Difference between ConfigurationManager.GetSection and Configuration.GetSection?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, config

I'm trying to create a custom config file section based on AppSettings:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="customConfiguration" 
           type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, 
                 System.Configuration, 
                 Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</configSections>
```

When I tried reading it via ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customConfiguration") the object returned was of type System.Configuration.KeyValueInternalCollection.  I was unable to read the values of this collection, although I could see the keys, and I couldn't cast it to an AppSettingsSection.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480367/216440) Stackoverflow answer suggests I should use

```
Configuration config = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AppSettingsSection customSettingSection = 
    (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("customConfiguration");
```

This worked.  My question is: What is the difference between ConfigurationManager.GetSection() and Configuration.GetSection()?  When should I use one and when should I use the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the MSDN documentation on the Configuration Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx,

> If your application needs read-only access to its own configuration, it is recommended that you use the [GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.getsection.aspx) method overloads for Web applications. For client application, use the [GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx) method.
>
> These methods provide access to the cached configuration values for the current application, which has better performance than the Configuration class.

Specifically, in client applications, the ConfigurationManager retrieves a configuration file obtained by merging the application configuration file, the local user configuration file, and the roaming configuration file.

Comment: So the Configuration.GetSection is for client apps, getting the section of the specified user configuration (for all users, current user's local profile or current user's roaming profile, depending on the ConfigurationUserLevel specified in OpenExeConfiguration)?  And ConfigurationManager.GetSection gets the section of the default configuration, which for client apps is the merged combination of all three user configurations (all users, current user's local profile, current user's roaming profile)? Why then do the two GetSection methods return different object types?

Comment: `System.Configuration.GetSection()` is generic and can be used for both web and client apps, while `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` is a wrapper optimized for client apps specifically.

Comment: @Claies does this mean that there is no default way to use `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration()` to open a different configuration file and have it perform well by using its returning `Configuration.GetSection()` to load a section. Since only `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` "performs well" but it uses the application's default configuration