# Reading Values from Web.config file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app. My app has a web.config app. In this app, I have a custom section that looks like this:

```
<service.settings>
  <service1 isEnabled="true" emailAddress="someone@somewhere.com" />
  <service2 isEnabled="true" emailAddress="another@address.com" />
  <bonzai type="ficus" age="13" />
</service.settings>
```

My question is, how do I access these configuration values in my C# code? I'm familiar with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. However, I'm not sure how to get configuration settings out of custom sections.

Comment: sounds like a possible duplicate of this possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471234/how-to-create-a-custom-section-that-behaves-like-an-appsettings-section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Assuming 'service.settings' is on the root of your web.config...
var yourSection = (YourSectionClass)ConfigurationManager
   .GetSection("service.settings")
```